# CultureInfo from RegionInfo using LINQ

Tags: c#, linq, globalization

Need some help as this is driving me insane and I can't tell if I'm doing something stupid or not.

I'm trying to gather a list of all specific cultures and get their corresponding RegionInfo. from that list I'm attempting to get the region corresponding to a country supplied by a parameter. I'm attempting this through LINQ, as seen below;

```
public RegionInfo getregion(string country)
{
    RegionInfo thisregion;
    List<RegionInfo> regions = new List<RegionInfo>();
    CultureInfo[] allregions = CultureInfo.GetCultures(CultureTypes.SpecificCultures);
    regions.AddRange(allregions.Where(x => !x.IsNeutralCulture).Select(x => new RegionInfo(x.LCID)));
    thisregion = regions.FirstOrDefault(region => region.EnglishName == country);
    return thisregion;
}
```

This particular function keeps throwing an exception during the Select() statement, error below;

> Additional information: Culture ID 4096 (0x1000) is a neutral culture;
>   a region cannot be created from it.

The culture in question causing the issue is aa-ER. As you can see, I have filtered the list based on the IsNeutralCulture Boolean, so  the net framework doesn't think this culture is neutral, yet the error says otherwise.

Am I doing something stupid?

EDIT: Interestingly, the first comment lead me to test it on a different machine, which didn't throw the error on the same culture. Looks like a machine problem.

Comment: I'm executing your code on my machine and it is fine .... Can you please say that is the `country` your are using? Shouldn't be related but better test it

Comment: Country in this case is Czech Republic, however the code doesn't get that far.

Comment: Works for me as well.  But I notice that I do not have aa-ER in allregions.  allregions count is 248.

Comment: Interestingly, the first comment lead me to test it on a different machine, which didn't throw the error on the same culture. Looks like a machine problem.

Comment: @RyanHargreaves did you check the OS versions? Are they the same?

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos Yes, both Windows 10

Comment: Restarting Azure web site solved my issue.

Answer (score 10):

OK, so as a workaround to this issue, I changed the Select statement to initialise RegionInfo for x.Name instead of x.LCID and this has worked. Don't know why the LCID was failing, but this solution will do.

Comment: I had similar issue. Sometimes the same code throws errors and sometimes not (on the same machine). It was fixed in .Net: https://github.com/dotnet/runtime/issues/64893

Also using `x.Name` in my case fixed the problem.